# Microsoft Access 07 VBA: Using Text Box or Combo Box as a Control to hide Columns

Tags: vba, text, hide

I currently have a form. The form contains a subform that displays a Query. The Form also has 2 Text Boxes and buttons for both Boxes. The first box acts as a filter for the query to filter specific record. The second box is intended to be used to hide columns in the query. My issue is that my code will not recognize the text box, or any outside source from my form as a Field Name to be found. Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub Command137_Click()

Forms![Vermont]![Query1 subform].Form.[Query1 Field Name].ColumnHidden = True

End Sub
```

Currently if I replace "Query1 Field Name" with any field name that exists in the query the column will hide. However if replaced with anything else I recieve the following error:

"Runtime Error '2465'
Microsoft Access Can't Find the Field '|' reffered to in your expression"

I am pretty sure that I am not referencing the Form Control correctly. I have tried replacing [Query1 Field Name] with the following:

```
[Text142.Text]
[=Text142]
[Text142]
[Forms![Vermont]![Text142]]
```

I am very new to VBA but I definitely feel as if this is an easy fix; if possible.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Subform references are always a bit weird.  This should work, though:

```
Forms![Vermont]![Query1 subform]![Text142].ColumnHidden = True
```